# Why Should I Save URL's Bookmark Data To The Preferences

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, filesystems, nsfilemanager, nsworkspace

Hey friends I came up with the question today that I have a window where I am adding users selected folder in my app from NSOpenSavePanel. I was accessing all the files and folders properly but as soon as I quit my app I am not able to open those folder because when I am giving path to open those files or folders it is showing pop up `You don't have permission to access this folder`

I saved BookMark data to my app's preferences and now it is working fine.

The question was ; What exactly is happening ?

Looking forward to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is the [App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html). The idea is that the user controls to what files an app has access.

For a **one time** access everything is handled for you. But if you want keep access across launches of your app you need to store and restore a bookmark.

You find all details about this in: [Security-Scoped Bookmarks and Persistent Resource Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16)